# Parameter is not valid. Image from Stream Error

Tags: image, base64, memorystream

```
public Image DecodeImage ( string _EncodedImage )
{
  byte[] _ByteArray = System . Convert . FromBase64String ( _EncodedImage );
  MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream ( _ByteArray , 0 , _ByteArray . Length );
  _Image = Image . FromStream ( _MemoryStream );
  return _Image;
}
```

> Parameter is not valid.

*Note, I tried:

- `Image _Image = new Bitmap ( _MemoryStream )`
- `_MemoryStream . Seek ( 0 , SeekOrigin . Begin );`
- `Bitmap _Bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(_MemoryStream , true, false);`

And got the same error

Comment: I use a similar snippet that I got from [this post](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, the array doesn't represent valid image data.

Look at `_ByteArray` (in the debugger, or print it out), and see what you've got. If something looks off, maybe save the binary data to a file and see how an image editor responds to it.

(by the way, you don't need to tell `MemoryStream` about the length of your byte array, not unless you want to use only a part of the array. `... = new MemoryStream (_ByteArray)` is fine)